# Convert disk from UEFI boot to BIOS boot

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, bios, efi

I have a disk with a Windows 10 installation on a laptop that has suffered an unfortunate accident. I know the hard disk is still good, and now I'd like to move this disk, including the existing Windows installation, to an older laptop I have sitting around. There are things installed here such that re-installing the OS, applications, and rebuilding my profile on the replacement machine would take a lot of work I'd like to avoid.

Unfortunately, the older laptop does not support UEFI boot/GPT disks. I do know the older laptop runs Windows 10 just fine generally (I've had it on this laptop previously).

Is it possible to convert this disk to Legacy/MBR mode in place, or will I need to re-install Windows? If it's possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to copy the data, convert the disk, copy it back, and then use a recovery tool  (I use [Macrium](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) personally).

Start by copying your existing partition files to a temporary location, such as an external drive, large flash drive, or different computer.

When that is done, boot off the rescue media and bring up a command prompt. From there, you should be able to use the `DISKPART` command, `select disk` for the disk you want to convert, `CLEAN` it from it's current GPT configuration and run `CONVERT MBR`. You may also need to specify the file system that you want to use; `format fs=ntfs` is an example of the command you'd use if you wished to use an NTFS configuration. Create the MSR partition and allocate the size (usually 128MB), with the command:

```
create partition msr size=128.
```

Exit the command prompt after creating that MBR Disk. You should now be able to transfer any existing data, including the Windows OS files you copied previously, back to the partition you just created on the original disk.

Now you can run the recovery utility fully. If your OS boots up, you can check the BIOS version in the start menu, by checking the `System Information`. It should say "BIOS" if done correctly.

I've run this procedure to convert from BIOS to UEFI, so I'm sure converting from UEFI to BIOS would entail a similar procedure. You might have some boot issues when making this conversion, but I know Macrium provides a tool to automatically resolve this issue as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like this would destroy the existing installation.

Comment: If you have the OS and additional data copied and stored somewhere that isn't the disk you are cleaning, then you should be able to make the conversion from GPT to MBR, move the copied data back over and then run the recovery. It shouldn't destroy the existing installation.

Answer (score 0):

This will be slow and tedious, but it should be possible via [DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism---deployment-image-servicing-and-management-technical-reference-for-windows):

- [Prepare a flash drive with WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive), and use it to boot into the WinPE environment on the source machine.
- Connect another (large) flash drive to the computer.
- Use [`DISM /capture-image`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image) to create a `*.wim` file representing the original system and save it to the second large flash drive. Normally you'd do this in conjunction with `sysprep`, but since we're moving the *same installation*, rather than wanting a generic installation, I think we can skip this.
- Shutdown the source system and boot into WinPE on the target system. In the context of the question, that means moving the hard disk over to the target system.
- Use `diskpart` in WinPE to prepare the disk for an MBR installation, including both Windows and system (boot) partitions. This will reformat the disk and wipe all data. The question doesn't want that, but it's okay... the *.wim file we made earlier has everything we need to rebuild it.
- Connect the second flash drive and use [`DISM /apply-image`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image) to load the image from the drive onto the disk that was just prepared.
- Use [bcdboot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-deployment-command-line-tools-reference) to deploy the bootloader to the system partition created while using diskpart.

Again, several of the steps can take a **long** time, and this is just an overview of the full process. The actual commands to run can get quite involved and vary system to system.

Note it is possible to only use flash drive here, and save the *.wim file to the same drive as the WinPE environment, but setting this up is not trivial. Most people will find it easier to use two drives.